# ado.net remove rows and update to datasource

Tags: c#, ado.net

I used `DataTable.Rows.Remove` to remove some rows, and use `DataAdapter.Update` to update this table to datasource, but it doesn't work:

#### Code:

```
public void Delete(T[] values)
    {
        foreach (var val in values)
        {
            var row = m_Dict[val];
            m_Table.Rows.Remove(row);
            m_Elements.Remove(val);
            m_Dict.Remove(val);
        }
    }

public void Apply(SqlDataAdapter adapter)
    {
        using (new SqlCommandBuilder(adapter))
        {
            adapter.UpdateBatchSize = 5;
            adapter.Update(m_Table);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Removing rows doesnt remove from the DB

Comment: Now I want to remove from the DB,how to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you want DataRow.Delete. The key to this is understanding the concept of "row states" in ADO.NET. DataRow.Delete will set the row state to Deleted.

Related info: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/03c7a3zb(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Thank you for your reply! It‘s my fault,I just want to delete some rows in datatable, and update to datasource,then the database doesn't include these rows no longer.I found I used DataRow.Delete and don't use DataTable.AcceptChange,the Upadate.It's well done.